# ImportError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I installed Python 3.5. I ran the `pip install google` command and verified the modules. Google was present.

I installed [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) 3.5 and tried to run z sample code. But I'm getting the import error. Please find the screen shot attached.
What am I missing? Do I have to link my Spyder to Python installation directory in some way? Why is Spyder unable to google module?

My Python installation directory: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35

[image]

[image]

<sub>My scenario is a bit different and I could not find a solution from similar posts here.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

- I had to delete my Anaconda and Python installations
- Re-install Anaconda only
- Open the Anaconda prompt and point it to `Anaconda/Scripts`
- Run `pip install google`
- Run the sample code now from Spyder.

No more errors.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, The key of the solution is Re-install Anaconda only and install it after the cudnn! :P

Comment: what does this: "Open Anaconda prompt and point it to Anaconda/Scripts" mean, what are the steps to reproduce this action?

Comment: I have the same question. What does "point it to Anaconda/Scripts" mean? I had opened my Anaconda prompt but did not know what to do to "point it to Anaconda/Scripts".

Answer (score 158):

According to https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client#installation, you need to install the google-api-python-client package:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to the generic page *https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client*

Comment: Thank you @PeterMortensen, I have updated the link

Answer (score 45):

Use this both installation and then go ahead with your Python code:

```
pip install google-cloud
pip install google-cloud-vision
```

Comment: I dunno why this works, but it works. pip install google didn't work.

Comment: why does this work? worked for me

Comment: Seems google doesn't properly handle their requirements.

Answer (score 29):

I could fix it by installing the following directly.

```
pip install google.cloud.bigquery
pip install google.cloud.storage
```

Answer (score 15):

Kindly executing these commands,

```
pip install google
pip install google-api-core
```

will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: This solved my problem among a lot of other ways.

Comment: worked for me 2

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same issue, and I was trying to import translate from google.cloud, but I kept getting the same error.

This is what I did

1. `pip install protobuf`
2. `pip install google-cloud-translate`

And to install the storage service from google `google-cloud-storage`, it should be installed separately.

Ref - https://cloud.google.com/python/

Comment: Was protobuf in my case.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem in this way:

1. `sudo pip install conda`
2. `pip install google`

The error got resolved.

Answer (score 5):

I got this from cloud service documentation:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-translate
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar error when I tried to access the bigquery from google.cloud.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

The error was resolved after I installed the google.cloud from conda-forge community.

```
conda install -c conda-forge google-cloud-bigquery
```

Comment: Any ideas why is `google-cloud-bigquery` only available in conda-forge?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar import problem. I noticed that there was no `__init__.py` file in the root of the `google` package. So, I created an empty `__init__.py` and now the import works.

Comment: This did not work for me (python 3.7, macOS 10.13.6)

Comment: Verify first whether you have package installed through PIP or not? If Yes, then please check the Directory path and if not then you have to again use the above 2 commands to install it

Answer (score 1):

For Python-Flask application.

If nothing helps,

1. Uninstall flask (pip uninstall flask)
2. Uninstall python from your machine
3. Restart the machine and make sure uninstall is done properly
4. Re-install python and flask again
5. Run `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`
6. Run your application

It should be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was uninstalling Anaconda (in my case, Spyder), install the required google clients (`google-api-python-client` will do), then reinstall Anaconda.

This should solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I know its frustrating to make it done. Its not hit and try to be honest.

first step to setup google apis

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

second- look and read your DAG and see what is source/destination or other GCP platform you are using such as if you are taking data from bigquery then

```
pip install bigquery 
or pip install xyz-google-stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same error while trying vision API

```
    from google.cloud import vision
    import io
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
```

got no module named 'google'

so I added a line

```
import google
```

in such a way,

```
import google
    from google.cloud import vision
    import io
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
```

and it worked for me.:)

Answer (score -1):

1. Close Anaconda/Spyder
2. Open command prompt and run the below command
3. **conda update --all**
4. Start the app again and this time it should work.

**Note - You need not have to uninstall/reinstall anything.**

Answer (score -2):

Kindly executing these commands

If you are using the python2 version:

- pip install google
- pip install google-api-core

If you are using the python3 version:

- pip3 install google
- pip3 install google-api-core

will definitely solve your problem.