# Error in importing compiled protobuf in gRPC framework with Python

Tags: python, grpc, protocol-buffers

I've written a service with gRPC. When I start the service, it can't import compiled protobuf and shows the following error message:

```
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptortitus| ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried to reproduct your problem.

And there is all fine in my configuration.

Looks like there is [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183486/importerror-no-module-named-google) `google` packages in `pip`.
And one named `google` actually not official google's package.
Did you used `pip install google` to install google package?

I did it as below

```sh
pip install protobuf
```

```sh
pip freeze
```

```
protobuf==3.13.0
six==1.15.0
```

```py
from google.protobuf import descriptor
dir(descriptor)
```

```
['Descriptor', 'DescriptorBase', 'DescriptorMetaclass', 'EnumDescriptor', 'EnumValueDescriptor', 'Error', 'FieldDescriptor', 'FileDescriptor', 'MakeDescriptor', 'MethodDescriptor', 'OneofDescriptor', 'ServiceDescriptor', 'TypeTransformationError', '_Deprecated', '_Lock', '_NestedDescriptorBase', '_OptionsOrNone', '_ParseOptions', '_ToCamelCase', '_ToJsonName', '_USE_C_DESCRIPTORS', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_internal_create_key', '_lock', '_message', 'api_implementation', 'binascii', 'os', 'six', 'threading', 'warnings']
```

My python version is

```sh
Python 3.6.7 (default, Dec  5 2018, 15:02:05) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```