# Module not found even if it is in pip

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I had installed a module with the command `pip install google`. It worked file but when I try to run files with this module it gives error.

[image: The image of error]

My code:-

```
from google import search

ip=raw_input("What would you like to search for? ")

for url in search(ip, stop=20):
     print(url)
```

I have already installed google.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Notes:-

1. I have only 1 python installed (Python 3.9.5)
2. Even after using command `python -m pip install google` it doesn't work.
   [image: Image- Module not found]

**Thank you!**

Comment: Maybe you have several `python`s installed, and when invoking the script you are using the one which does not have a package. Try `sys.executable` from within your script, to see what interpreter is used. (See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589711/find-full-path-of-the-python-interpreter)

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183486/importerror-no-module-named-google)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I found myself the solution. Thanks to @user42 for the link. I used this command and it worked.

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

I have put the answer because it may help people who are facing or will be facing the **same problem**.

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than 1 python installed, there is chance pip installed google in different python. To make sure it does install module for python you are using do:

```
python -m pip install google
```

Then try running your code again. If you want to know more about `install`ing you might read [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage).

Comment: I did that command too, pls check the edited question. And I did not understand what are you telling about "several pythons" I have only 1 installed Python-3.9.5

Comment: But your code example contains `raw_input` and `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3. If you present us code for Python 2 and error messages from Python 3 we have to assume that you have at least 2 different versions of Python installed.