# No module named 'Google' after installing google in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages

Tags: python

I had tried everything from [ImportError: No module named 'google'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183486/importerror-no-module-named-google). And google package had successfully installed. However, it still kept showing the error of

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-eaccd5d99904> in <module>
----> 1 from Google import Create_Service

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Google'
```

What did I do wrong? Please help me.

Comment: Check which version of python has installed the module (assuming you used `pip install google`) and see if its the same version of python being used to run the script

Comment: installed `google-api-python-client`?

Comment: Make sure installed package is in path

Comment: If you installed the package with pip can you do `pip show google-api-python-client`? what version of python are you using?

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I uninstalled my Anaconda, and reinstalled the new version (Anaconda 3). The pip install paths are all correct. However, it still doesn't work.

Comment: My input and output are https://ibb.co/k2hpfzv , https://ibb.co/R07qy2H ,and https://ibb.co/Z22fZ1q.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using?